# How to display two columns of blocks with CSS

Tags: css

I have to create two columns of blocks with CSS from the following HTML code:

```
<nav>
  <a href="http://www.link1.net/">Link 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.link2.org/">Link 2/a>
  <a href="http://www.link3.com/">Link 3</a>
  <a href="http://www.link4.net/">Link 4</a>
  <a href="http://www.link5.net/">Link 5</a>
  <a href="http://www.link6.org/">Link 6</a>
  <a href="http://www.link7.org/">Link 7</a>
  <a href="http://www.link8.org/">Link 8</a>
</nav>
```

Two columns must look like that:

```
Link1 Link2

Link3 LInk4

Link5 Link6

Link7 LInk8
```

Blocks have the fixed width of 300px and background `color #808080`. Anyone know how to do this? I would be really gratefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
nav {
  width: 600px
}
a {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="http://www.link1.net/">Link 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.link2.org/">Link 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.link3.com/">Link 3</a>
  <a href="http://www.link4.net/">Link 4</a>
  <a href="http://www.link5.net/">Link 5</a>
  <a href="http://www.link6.org/">Link 6</a>
  <a href="http://www.link7.org/">Link 7</a>
  <a href="http://www.link8.org/">Link 8</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant with CSS3 and pseudoselector nth-child - no matters which width.

```
nav a:nth-child(2n) {
    clear:none;
    display:block;
}

nav a:nth-child(2n+1) {
    float:left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ddygtyx/)